# painting surface of an irregular game object with different colours

Tags: blender, 3d-modelling

I have a custom game object (irregular rock stone). I have to colour the part of the surfaces in blue, red, orange and yellow. I have tried many options of shaders, textures and vertext painting. Since my object is an single custom made object ( imported as .obj) I am able to change the colour of the whole object only. 
Could some one direct me how can I change the colour of part of surfaces of my game object with different fixed colours, not just programmatically but permanently.[Rock with faces in different fixed colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meCQ3.png)

Comment: Um - just open the PNG texture, and change it.  (Using, say, photoshop.)  This has no connection at all to Unity, as such. Close Unity. Look for the FBX (or whatever) file of the rock.  You'll see the texture which is a PNG file.  Open the file in photoshop, and as an experiment make a big "X" somewhere.  Now open the Unity project and you'll see that.

Comment: Thanks for that. I hv tried that too. The problem was mapping  regions. It'd too complicated to identify the corresponding regions. I also used blender to unwrap UVs but unfortunately as I had multiple objects bringing back UVs to unity created mapping errors.

Comment: 3D art is hard, but making code solutions for something which is elementary 3d art is harder. Ask a 3d artist. If you're having problems importing legal 3d art to unity, then that's a question about unity.

Comment: @user6160538 use blender, dont unwrap it again, just slap on the texture you have with the uv map you have. then go to texture paint mode and color what side you want in what color you want in 3d. if that isnt sufficiently precise, save the newly painted texture, export the uv layout and import both in photoshop/gimp and use the uv-layout to mask the areas "triangle-perfect" (almost perfect, in the end its pixel-, not vector art). if you are familiar with all i said, it will only take you a few minutes.

Comment: texture painting ("unfolding" or "mapping") is incredibly difficult. As @yes explains, **this is the purpose of Blender**, just do it in Blender.